# How to set page sizing of pdf with Knp Snappy bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, symfony-2.8, knp-snappy

I have a code which use to work to generate PDF with the KNP Snappy bundlde with Symfony2. This is what it looks like:

> ```
>      $this->container->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
>           $this->templating->render(
>              $twigInclude,
>              array( ,
>                  'htmlFiles' => $htmlFiles,
>                  'headlines' => $headlines,
>              )
>          ),
>          $folderHistory . '/reports/' . $filename . '.pdf'
>      );
> ```

My issue is that, I want to set margins and change page size from A4 to A1. I have found so many examples but everytime I try, it seems like the pdf does not generate anymore. How can I solve this issue and make that work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flags you can set within options:

```
$options = [
  'page-size' => 'A1',
  'margin-top' => 10,
  'margin-right' => 10,
  'margin-bottom' => 10,
  'margin-left' => 10,
];

$this->container->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
  $this->templating->render(
    $twigInclude,
    [
      'htmlFiles' => $htmlFiles,
      'headlines' => $headlines,
    ]
  ),
  $folderHistory . '/reports/' . $filename . '.pdf',
  $options,
  true // this flag will overwrite existing file
);
```